# Shiros Sha256Hash and alternative algorithms

Tags: shiro, hmac, sha256, pbkdf2

Is Sha256Hash from Apache Shiro based upon a common specification like PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256?

The following example proves, Shiros Sha256Hash doesn't create a valid PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 hashes.

```java
public static byte[] getEncryptedPassword(
    String password,
    byte[] salt,
    int iterations,
    int derivedKeyLength
) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(
        password.toCharArray(),
        salt,
        iterations,
        derivedKeyLength * 8
    );
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    return f.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
}

@Test
public void testHashing(){
    byte[] salt = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator().nextBytes().getBytes();
    byte[] hash1 = new Sha256Hash("1234", salt, 1024).getBytes();
    byte[] hash2 = getEncryptedPassword("1234", salt, 1024, 32);
    assertTrue(hash1.equals(hash2));
}
```

Is there a common way to use PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 with shiro, or do I have to implement my own CredentialMatcher?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Shiro user list on nabble](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Password-hashing-with-PBKDF2-td7577741.html) no, Shiro does not provide PBKDF2 (or BCrypt or SCrypt).

Note that [Java 8 does have PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 available now](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) as PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 - use that instead.  SHA-512 in particular has 64-bit operations that reduce the advantage GPU based attackers have.  Use more iterations than just 1024, as well - see what your system can handle comfortably under load!